# единая функция для нескольких датафреймов в pandas

Tags: python, функции, pandas, dataframe

Коллеги, помогите с написанием одной функции для нескольких датафреймов.

к примеру имеется 3 одинаковых датафрейма но разные по годам

df2014:

```
id   'оборотные активы' 'активы'  'капитал  'крат.об-ва' 
123     19764         2746539     472        2854 
497     49287         2980756     5283       9782
```

df2015:

```
id   'оборотные активы' 'активы'  'капитал  'кратк.об-ва' 
12     36728            2567834     192837        39280 
97    2908             9427689     3209849       198
```

необходимо рассчитать коэфф. показателей и добавить в каждый датафрейм в новые столбцы. Хочется написать одну функцию типа def ratios (df), которую через apply можно было подставить к соответствующему датафрейму.

результат примерно должен был выглядеть вот так:

df2014:

```
id   'оборотные активы' 'активы'  'капитал  'крат.об-ва'  'wc'  'cl'    'er'
123     19764         2746539     472        2854         16910  6.925   0.00017
497     49287         2980756     5283       9782         39505  5.03   0.0017
```

я попытался написать следующую функцию, но кажись некорректно применяю:

```
def ratios(df):
   df['wc'] = df['оборотные активы'] - df['крат.об-ва']
   df['cl'] = df['оборотные активы'] / df['крат.об-ва']
   df['er'] = df['капитла'] / df['активы']
   return df
df2014 = df2014.apply(ratios)
```

но увы кроме ошибок ничего не выходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ratios (df):
    df['wc'] = df['оборотные активы'] - df['крат.об-ва']
    df['cl'] = df['оборотные активы'] / df['крат.об-ва']
    df['er'] = df['капитал'] / df['активы']
    return df
```

Проверка:

```
In [30]: res = ratios(df2014)

In [31]: res
Out[31]:
    id  оборотные активы   активы  капитал  крат.об-ва     wc        cl        er
0  123             19764  2746539      472        2854  16910  6.925018  0.000172
1  497             49287  2980756     5283        9782  39505  5.038540  0.001772
```

---

```
In [36]: res2015 = ratios(df2015)

In [37]: res2015
Out[37]:
   id  оборотные активы   активы  капитал  крат.об-ва    wc         cl        er
0  12             36728  2567834   192837       39280 -2552   0.935031  0.075097
1  97              2908  9427689  3209849         198  2710  14.686869  0.340470
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Как всегда - великолепно!!!

Comment: @Pavel, я просто использовал написанную вами функцию ;)